# Set Windows 10 Default Start Layout

Tags: group-policy, scripting, windows-10, wds

How can we set the default start layout and task bar icons for each user in Windows 10, yet still let users modify them later?

I know you can use an XML file to set these, but a standard XML file locks them down and a partial start layout does not allow for removing the junk that windows includes in the start menu.

CopyProfile explicitly does not work on the start menu and task bar according to Microsoft.

How can this be done?

Comment: Is this at Windows 10 Enterprise or Pro?

Comment: It's Windows 10 Pro

Comment: You can modify the system image default start layout using PowerShell. Here are the `cmdlets` that are what you are looking for: `Import-StartLayout` and`Export-StartLayout`. If you are using `Windows 10 Enterprise`, you can use the `cloud content` group policy to remove the extra junk that windows includes and because of this you can manage it through group policy using the partial layout without having to worry about the junk. If this solves your issue, I will rewrite this as an answer.